# How to allow user to set background of a custom android launcher

Tags: android, background, launcher

I wanted to provided users with an option to set the background my custom launcher. However, the code I tried only set the background of the default home screen and not of my launcher. Can I make the code to change the background of my custom launcher.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by launcher? You can just put some buttons up and have each one do something along the lines of this

```
public void setActivityBackgroundColor(int color) {
        View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
```

and obviously change the color to the ones you want them to be able to select.

Comment: thank you for your reply. No, I am not looking to change the background color. Launcher is to provide an alternative to the android home screen. So, I would like to provide users with an opportunity to change the background of my launcher home screen. But I am only able to get it to change the background of the default android home screen